# Insert Contents of CSV into strings

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, datagrid

I've been struggling with a small piece of code for a little while now. I have a CSV file with one column that contains a string of numbers. I can import that file without issues and display it.

My goal is to take the numbers in each of the tables and put it into a separate string, run that string through a function and then put the results back into my datagrid in column two. Is there a way that I should be doing this using the code below; the foreach statement is where I believe this should be done.

Edit: I tweaked the code and it now works the way that I want it to but I can't insert my result into any columns except for the first one. Is there a way that I should be targeting the results so they go in the second column?

```
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(Dialog.FileName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
            {

                List<string> lista = new List<string>();
                List<string> listb = new List<string>();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                    lista.Add(values[0]);
                    dt1.Rows.Add(values[0]);
                }
                foreach (var item in lista)
                {
                    string temp;
                    GetLuhnCheckDigit(item);
                    listb.Add(last.ToString());
                    temp = item + last.ToString();

                    dt1.Rows.Add(temp); //This only adds to the first column
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `GetLuhnCheckDigit` method does, it is not possible to determine what values you want the second column to contain. Looking at the posted code, there are many things missing like how many columns the data table has, where is the `Dialog` variable definition? What is `last`?

Assuming there are at least two columns in the `DataTable` `dt1`, I am not sure why you are adding the items to the first column then loop through a list of those items to set the second column. It appears adding both of the columns at the same time would be easier.

You could do all this while reading the file like below:

```
try {
  using (var fs = File.OpenRead(Dialog.FileName)) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs)) {

      List<string> lista = new List<string>();
      List<string> listb = new List<string>();
      string temp;

      while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        lista.Add(values[0]);
        GetLuhnCheckDigit(values[0]); // <-- What is this method doing??? 
        listb.Add(last.ToString());
        temp = values[0] + last.ToString();
        dt1.Rows.Add(values[0], temp); // <-- this adds both columns
      }
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
}
```

Let me know if I am missing something, as I am clueless as to what the `GetLuhnCheckDigit` method could be doing.

Comment: This did the trick. The GetLuhnCheckDigit function simply requests a string and generates a number based on the inserted string; More info here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm.